# It is necessary to convert data into string before making a POST/PUT request

Tags: angular, http, https, axios

When we do a API request POST/PUT, we do JSON.stringify(body), is it necessary ?

**Axis** by default stringify data (i know you can modify that) before making a request and in **Angular** also we need to stringify data.

**Is there anything related to security?**

Comment: short answer: no and no :)

Comment: if no then why Axis and angular do it automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

With the deprecated Http modules yes, after Angular 4+ with the new HttpClientModule it's all automatic, you no longer need to call this function yourself. Some people assume that you don't need to do this, but if you have an app in production builded before Angular 4 you need to follow the old rules.

Give it a read:
https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#http

Edit: 15/11/2019

As you can see here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/request.ts

The HttpClientModule now does the JSON.stringify(this.body) automatically

This is how HttpClientModule handle post request:

```
constructor(method: 'POST'|'PUT'|'PATCH', url: string, body: T|null, init?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders,
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    params?: HttpParams,
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
  });
```

And this is how now HttpClientModule automatically do the JSON.Stringify()

```
 /**
   * Transform the free-form body into a serialized format suitable for
   * transmission to the server.
   */
  serializeBody(): ArrayBuffer|Blob|FormData|string|null {
    // If no body is present, no need to serialize it.
    if (this.body === null) {
      return null;
    }
    // Check whether the body is already in a serialized form. If so,
    // it can just be returned directly.
    if (isArrayBuffer(this.body) || isBlob(this.body) || isFormData(this.body) ||
        typeof this.body === 'string') {
      return this.body;
    }
    // Check whether the body is an instance of HttpUrlEncodedParams.
    if (this.body instanceof HttpParams) {
      return this.body.toString();
    }
    // Check whether the body is an object or array, and serialize with JSON if so.
    if (typeof this.body === 'object' || typeof this.body === 'boolean' ||
        Array.isArray(this.body)) {
      return JSON.stringify(this.body);
    }
    // Fall back on toString() for everything else.
    return (this.body as any).toString();
  }
```

Now looking to the old implementation will be this:

```
 /**
   * Performs a request with `post` http method.
   */
  post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return httpRequest(
        this._backend, new Request(mergeOptions(
                           this._defaultOptions.merge(new RequestOptions({body: body})), options,
                           RequestMethod.Post, url)));
```

But without a serializeBody() method, instead of serializeBody there is only a blob serialize

```
  /**
    * Returns the request's body as a Blob, assuming that body exists.
    */
  blob(): Blob {
    if (this._body instanceof Blob) {
      return <Blob>this._body;
    }

    if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      return new Blob([this._body]);
    }

    throw new Error('The request body isn\'t either a blob or an array buffer');
  }
}
```

Where you manually need to serialize, like docs suggest:

```
create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
  return this.http
    .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json().data as Hero)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: But why Angular stringify body ?

Comment: From the docs of old Angular 2: To identify which hero the server should update, the hero id is encoded in the URL. The put() body is the JSON string encoding of the hero, obtained by calling JSON.stringify. The body content type (application/json) is identified in the request header.

Refresh the browser, change a hero name, save your change, and click the browser Back button. Changes should now persist.

Docs: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html